# Get installing package name from package installer activity

Tags: android

Is it possible to get package name of the installing application **before app installed**. i.e., While showing installer activity itself can we find?

[image: Installer activity]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can get package name of application from .apk file using its filepath.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageArchiveInfo(filepath,PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
if(packageInfo != null) {
  ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageInfo.applicationInfo;
  String package_name= appInfo.packageName;
}
```

where filepath is a String containing filepath of the apk e.g. "/sdcard/xyz.apk".
Make sure you add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE uses permission in AndroidManifest.xml

I hope this helps.

Comment: This can be done only after app installed right? But i need before app installation.:-(

Comment: You can get the package name whenever you want. You just need the filepath. I have used it before apps installation. Try it.